# Is it secure way to store private values in .env file?

Tags: node.js, express, security, dotenv

I'm trying to build a node.js server with express framework, and I want to store a private key for admin APIs in my server.
I'm now using .env file to store those values, and in my routes, using that values by calling like `process.env.ADMIN_KEY`.

**Question**
Is it secure way to handle private datas? or there's another way better than this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is more secure to store your secrets in a .env file than in the source code itself. But you can do one better. Here are the ways I've seen secrets managed, from least to most secure:

1. Hard-code the secrets in the code.

   - Pros: None. Don't do this.
   - Cons: Your developers will see your production secrets as part of their regular work. Your secrets will be checked into source control. Both are security risks. Also, you have to modify the code to use it in different environments, like dev, test, and production.
2. Put secrets in environment variables, loaded from a .env file.

   - Pros: Developers won't see your production secrets. You can use different secrets in dev, test, and production, without having to modify the code.
   - Cons: Malicious code can read your secrets. The bulk of your application's code is probably open-source libraries. Bad code may creep in without you knowing it.
3. Put secrets in a dedicated secret manager, like [Vault by HashiCorp](https://www.vaultproject.io/) or [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) by Google Cloud.

   - Pros: It's harder for malicious code to read your secrets. You get auditing of who accessed secrets when. You can assign fine-grained roles for who updates secrets and who can read them. You can update and version your secrets.
   - Cons: It's additional technology that you have to learn. It may be an additional piece of software that you need to set up and manage, unless it's included in the cloud platform you're using.

So the choice is really between items 2 and 3 above. Which one you pick will depend on how sensitive your secrets are and how much extra work it would be to use a dedicated secret manager. For example, if your project is running on Google Cloud Platform, the Secret Manager is just [one API call away](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/quickstart). It may be just as easy on the other major cloud platforms, but I don't have first-hand experience with them.

Comment: what is the use of creating env file on a private codebase?

Comment: @JobinS development and testing purposes

Comment: @JobinS Many people use different databases in dev, test, and prod environments. So you'd need different database addresses and passwords for these three environments.

Comment: But where would you store the api key password? If they can find that, they can access the API and still get all the secrets, no?

Comment: @SaroVerhees On Google Cloud your code runs as a service account, which has certain privileges determined by the admin. There is no need to supply an API key.

Comment: @SaroGFX you're absolutely right. Indeed env vars are susceptible to be stolen, so being them the actual api keys, passwords and so on, that you put in a secure store, or the secure store access keys and passwords to get them, they can get stolen. You just added an extra step to the keys, not any actual level of security,  now you also gave them access to the secure store. 
In case of Kubernetes for the app deployment, using by env file you can get the env file with just an exec command. 
So in the end Access points to your app are more important to secure.. Tls etc etc.

Answer (score 15):

Simple answer is **YES**, .env is used to store keys and secrets. It is not pushed to your repo i.e. github or bitbucket or anywhere you store your code. In that way it is not exposed.

Here are the tutorial links for correct usage:

- [managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-with-dotenv](https://stackabuse.com/managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-with-dotenv/)
- [how-secure-is-your-environment-file-in-node-js](https://codeburst.io/how-secure-is-your-environment-file-in-node-js-7c4d2ed0d15a)

Comment: Most secure way if you are using EBS, store all the secret env under EBS environment variables. And I am sure for other nodejs hosting services have the same capabilities.

Comment: I'm confused if it's not pushed to github and I use github repo as source for deployment on some cloud hosting, how will my deployed project use those secret values that lies within that `.env`?

Comment: @YvesNg if you're using physical or virtual machine i.e. EC2 or Azure VM etc then you can login in to the server then where your code/repo resides create .env and copy-past its contents. If you're using PaaS i.e. Heroku or something else then you can directly manage en variables without using .env file because they provide option for it.

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon so that means manually adding a number of variables. neat xD

Comment: what is the use of creating env file on a private codebase?

Comment: It is a possible way of keeping secrets hidden and also a way to manage the environment without polluting global stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Secrets stored in environment variables are in risk of getting exposed (for non-private node apps) as for example libraries you use might print the environment into the log in case of an error. So it would be more safe to store them in a file outside of source control and import it where needed.

https://movingfast.io/articles/environment-variables-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 1):

It is **yes**. An additional security check can be added by using encrypted values. Also avoid to checkin your .env file in public repo.

Answer (score 1):

The following demonstrates how to load environment variables and secret values into a software project for local development.

- **Step 1**: Create secret records in [Google Secret Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manager)
- **Step 2**: Save environment variables and secret references to `.env` file(s)
- **Step 3**: Add a call to `loadEnv(environment, options)` where you need those variables

### Basic Example

##### `.env` — environment variables

```
# Environment varialbes and secrets
# NOTE: You can reference secrets from a cloud secret manager by
#       following this pattern: secret://[provider]/[resource]

# Google Cloud
# https://console.cloud.google.com/
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=example
GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION=us-central1

# Cloud Identity Platform (a.k.a. Firebase Auth)
# https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity
FIREBASE_APP_ID=1:674174690042:web:bb8d27dcc9e48fc0a7690d
FIREBASE_API_KEY=BIzbEyGBAlkrEIvlYgZeub9LBCkYJM6ySIMF2Je
FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=example.com

# Cloudflare
# https://dash.cloudflare.com/
CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID=a8b47b39ab92525b2653229b28a1fc31
CLOUDFLARE_ZONE_ID=f3206a12cd93f45de116318496037c9f
CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN=secret://google/projects/example/secrets/cloudflare-api-token/versions/latest

# PostgreSQL Database
# https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.htm
PGHOST=34.172.75.101
PGPORT=5432
PGUSER=secret://google/projects/example/secrets/db-user/versions/latest
PGPASSWORD=secret://google/projects/example/secrets/db-password/versions/latest

# SendGrid
# https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys
EMAIL_FROM=hello@example.com
SENDGRID_API_KEY=secrets://google/projects/example/secrets/sendgrid-api-key/versions/latest
```

**NOTE**: Only `PGUSER`, `PGPASSWORD`, `CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN`, and `SENDGRID_API_KEY` are actually secrets in the example above. The rest environment variables can be included as plain text into `.env` files.

**NOTE**: You can reference secret values using the following pattern `secret://[provider]/[resource]`.

##### `./core/env.ts` — environment variables schema (validator)

To ensure that the app fails in case of any of the environment variables required by the app are missing or malformed, it's a good idea to create a validator (schema) similar to this:

```
import { cleanEnv, num, str } from "envalid";

export default cleanEnv(process.env, {
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT: str(),
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_REGION: str(),
  
  FIREBASE_APP_ID: str(),
  FIREBASE_API_KEY: str(),
  FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: str(),
  
  PGHOST: str(),
  PGPORT: num(),
  PGUSER: str(),
  PGPASSWORD: str(),

  EMAIL_FROM: str(),
  SENDGRID_API_KEY: str(),
});
```

##### `./vite.config.ts` — Vite configuration

If you're launching your Node.js app using Vite / Vite Node, you would load secrets inside of the `vite.configt.ts` file as follows:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { loadEnv } from "envars";

export default defineConfig(async ({ mode }) => {
  await loadEnv(mode, {
    root: ".",
    schema: "./core/env.ts",
    mergeTo: process.env,
  });

  return {
    build: {
      ssr: "index.ts",
      target: "esnext",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  };
});
```

**NOTE**: Normally, you want to use `loadEnv(...)` helper function just for local development and deployment. For example, if you deploy your app to Google Cloud Functions it supports secrets from Google Secret Manager natively.

#### References

- https://github.com/kriasoft/envars#readme
- https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs

Answer (score 0):

You can and should store secrets, credentials or private data securely inside a `.env` is a secure environment config section in your projects, useful for storing API keys and app credentials. Only invited collaborators are able to see the contents of your `.env` file.